# Doesn't the question "Can allah create a rock he can't lift" fall under primarily based opinions type?

Tags: discussion

The question is here, "[Can Allah create a rock that He can't lift?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11966/can-allah-create-a-rock-that-he-cant-lift)"

Other than these types of questions are not healthy (won't benefit majority of Islam.SE users in my humble opinion). From the 18 answers it is clear that answers are almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts. (Only 4 of them included sources from Quran to be fair)

So before I was going to flag it. I wanted to see if there was a valid reason for keeping it open so far.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that question is opinion-based, opinion based questions generally look like this;

- What do you think best ....... ?
- Do you think ..... is nice?

Central theme of those type of questions is that, it is impossible to either verify or refute an answer that is given to an opinion-based question. In other words, opinion-based questions has no right or wrong answer.

Answers to that question on the other hand, attempts to provide logical explanations to the problem. It doesn't matter they are all different explanations, so long as they are more than "I don't think so" answers, because reader can either accept or reject the provided explanation rationally.

Answer (score 1):

First, please note that [***reason*** is a major secondary source of Islamic Jurisprudence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sources_of_sharia#Reason) at least according to Shiism.

Secondly, note that Quran puts a strong emphasis on the role of reason, thinking and reflection in various verses.

Thirdly, theology (*kalam*) and Islamic philosophy are important fields of Islamic Knowledge and they both rely predominantly on logical reasoning for backing up Islamic beliefs.

Therefore, philosophical questions asking for logical proofs for Islamic beliefs are not opinion-based (at least not in the negative arbitrary sense of the term), they essentially invite reason-based arguments. If a post fails to provide a valid logical answer, then it is simply not a good answer.

Hence, there is every reason to allow philosophical questions about Islamic theological beliefs.

Answer (score 0):

This question has a major flaw, i.e. it's a stupid question.

This question tries to compare ALLAH with ordinary human being. This is like asking if ALLAH can eat food.

ALLAH doesn't have to lift weights. ALLAH orders and it happens. Gravity and mass are creations of ALLAH. ALLAH ordered and they came into being.

There are many such questions created by the devil to confuse people, one of them for example "If God exists then jump off a cliff and see if He can save you"